# How to make a basic Media player to play a video in avi format?

Tags: delphi-2010

I want to play a video in Delphi.
This is the code that I've got:

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute  then
 begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Display:=pnlVideo;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
 end;
```

But I get an error message:'The specified file cannot be played on the specified MCI device.The file may be corrupt, not in the correct format or no available file handler available for this format.'
The format of the video that I use is avi.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: AVI is just a container format. What matters are the codecs used by the streams inside the container. The basic media player has limited codec support. What codecs do you wish to support? Likely you will need a third party video playback control.

Comment: I have decided to use Windows media player instead because the media player is above my current skill set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a compatibility issue with the media player component in Delphi on our "modern" computers. I'm not tech savvy on what exactly the problem is :P. It is best to make your own component in Delphi to play media.

This link can help you make a Windows Media Player component, or you can adjust it to make another active X media player component - such as VLC.

https://chapmanworld.com/windows-media-player-in-delphi/

I hope this will help. :D